# Should there be a badge for asking a question with lots of downvotes?

Tags: discussion, badges

Do you think there should be a badge for asking a question with a lot of down votes?

Comment: Badges are there to encourage good behaviour, not the opposite!

Comment: @Oded Do you mean the "**Critic**" badge for "**First down vote**" is encouraging more down votes?

Comment: Meysam, downvoting bad questions (what the Critic badge is intended for) is behavior to be encouraged. *Asking* bad questions is not.

Comment: @Meysam: The Critic badge is meant to encourage voting in general. Given that down-voting an answer costs the voter one reputation point, many people don't vote.  But the system needs votes.  Even on questions/answers where the voter doesn't participate in any way other than voting.  The participation is important.

Comment: Are you asking if there is such a badge, or are you proposing such a badge is created? In the first case, you should not use [tag:feature-request]; in the second case, you should not ask a question.

Comment: @kiamlaluno I am asking if it's needed to request such badge.

Comment: In that case, I would change the question to "Do you think there should be a badge for asking a question with a lot of down votes?" I would also tag it [meta-tag:discussion], instead of [meta-tag:feature-request]. You are not asking for something to be implemented, but you are asking if it would be a good idea to implement it. Feature requests like this tends to get many down-votes.

Comment: @kiamlaluno edited the question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not really the kind of thing we want to encourage.

Keep in mind that, while on Meta a lot of down-votes simply means that the community disagrees with the post, on Stack Overflow and on the main (non-Meta) Stack Exchange sites in general down-votes means that it's a low quality post.  So, while on Meta it's OK, on the main sites we don't want low-quality posts.  (And, since Meta exists to support the main sites, one can assume that questions like this are referring to the main sites.)

The closest thing you'll find if the [Peer Pressure badge](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/38/peer-pressure).

Comment: +1 - The *on Meta a lot of down-votes simply means that the community disagrees with the post* can be a little jarring when you first encounter it on your question, as opposed to what it means on SO.

Answer (score 9):

**No!**  Hopefully nothing like this will ever be implemented.  We should be *discouraging* low-quality questions, not encouraging them.

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple already such as the [Question Blocked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/143965) badge or the [Day In the Penalty Box](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/) badge (thanks awoodland).

Comment: I was expecting that to be a link to one of the "a day in the penalty box" articles

Comment: couldn't think of the name of the post when I was searching. thanks - thats what i meant!

Comment: Well yes, except that the first one you linked to is *not* a temporary suspension.